# Отслеживание клика по верхнему элементу Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет. Поставил обработчик кликов на 2 элемента: родительский и дочерний. Дочерний элемент позиционируется абсолютно, что накладывает его сверху на родительский, т.е. он занимает часть от родительского. Но при клике по элементу, vue отслеживает клик и по родительскому элементу. Как быть? Мне необходимо, чтобы в случае клика по дочернему элементу, родительский элемент никак не это не реагировал.

```
<template>
    <div class="product" @click="openModal">
        <div class="image"><img :src="image" alt=""></div>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="status">
                        <p class="status__name">Статус товара</p>
                        <div class="status__image" @click="test"> //если кликаем сюда, родительский элемент тоже реагирует
                            <img src="img/cart.png" alt="">
                            <p>+</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <p class="name">{{name}}</p>
                    <p class="price">{{price}} Р</p>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['id', 'image', 'name', 'price'],
        data: function() {
            return {

            }
        },

        methods: {
            openModal: function() {
                this.$modal.show('hello-world');
            },
            test: function() {
                console.log(123);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: использовать модификатор [`.stop`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click.stop https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

```js
new Vue({
el: "#app",
        props: ['id', 'image', 'name', 'price'],
        data: function() {
            return {

            }
        },

        methods: {
            openModal: function() {
              console.log('modal')
            },
            test: function() {
              console.log("test");
            }
        }
    })
```

```css
.status {
  background: Lavender;
  height: 100vh;
}

.status__image {
  background: lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app" class="product" @click="openModal()">
        <div class="image"><img :src="image" alt=""></div>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="status">
                        <p class="status__name">Статус товара</p>
                        <div class="status__image" @click.stop="test()"> //если кликаем сюда, родительский элемент тоже реагирует
                            <img src="img/cart.png" alt="">
                            <p>+</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <p class="name">{{name}}</p>
                    <p class="price">{{price}} Р</p>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, можно проверять путь клика, и если там есть нужный или нет нужно класса, то просто пропускать действие.

Пример:

```js
new Vue({
el: "#app",
        props: ['id', 'image', 'name', 'price'],
        data: function() {
            return {

            }
        },

        methods: {
            openModal: function(e) {
            let result = false;
            for(let index in e.path) {
              let item = e.path[index]
              if (item.classList && item.classList[0] == 'status__image') result = true;
              }
                if(result) return ;
              console.log('modal')
                //this.$modal.show('hello-world');
            },
        }
    })
```

```css
.status {
  background: Lavender;
  height: 100vh;
}

.status__image {
  background: lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app" class="product" @click="openModal">
        <div class="image"><img :src="image" alt=""></div>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="status">
                        <p class="status__name">Статус товара</p>
                        <div class="status__image" > //если кликаем сюда, родительский элемент тоже реагирует
                            <img src="img/cart.png" alt="">
                            <p>+</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <p class="name">{{name}}</p>
                    <p class="price">{{price}} Р</p>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ваш вариант тоже хорош, но ниже дан ответ именно по vue.js

Comment: Да, тот вариант лучше